# SQL/Presto: how to choose rows if the values match with another table's

Tags: mysql, sql, presto, trino

I have 2 tables:

table 1:

```
task  cnt 
1      4
2      5
3      6
```

table 2:

```
task   cnt2
 1     7
 2     5
 3     6
 4     3
```

I want to add a column for table 2 such that if cnt in table1 for a task is the same as cnt2 for a task in table2. If there is no match, mark it as 'no match'

desired result:

```
 task  cnt2   if_matched
 1     7      'no match'
 2     5      'yes'
 3     6      'yes'
 4     3      'no match'
```

I started from a query like the one below to pick tasks that have matched values

```
  select task from table1 where table1.cnt = table2.cnt2
```

but I got an error for the where part.

Comment: At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial on MySQL would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join and case expression to calculate matched:

```
select t2.task, t2.cnt, 
       case when t1.task is null then 'no match' else 'yes' end as matched
  from table2 t2
       left join table1 t1 on t1.task=t2.task and t1.cnt = t2.cnt2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `exists`.  Both Presto and MySQL support boolean expressions, so you can use:

```
select t2.*,
       (exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.task = t2.task and t1.cnt = t2.cnt)
       ) as t1_matches
from table2 t2;
```

You can use a `case` expression to convert this to a string, but I prefer a boolean flag.

Note:  A left join can multiply the number of rows if there are multiple matches in `table1`.  That is the reason why I recommend `exists`.